# Magento2 add order ID in custom UI Component button link

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I want to add a view order button in form UI component of my custom module.
I've created a custom template for UI component link button but can't get the order id within URL.

The simple field for getting order id.

```
<field name="order_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order ID</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
            <item name="valuesForOptions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="text" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Link field for view order.

```
    <field name="order_view_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">7</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/custom-link</item>
                <item name="elementId" xsi:type="string">order_view_button</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
                <item name="dialogUrl" xsi:type="url" path="sales/order/view">
                    <param name="order_id">value</param>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">View Order</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Custom ui template custom-link.html

```
<a css="'action-advanced': $data.displayAsLink, 'action-secondary': !$data.displayAsLink" attr="'href': dialogUrl">
    <span text="title">View Order</span>
</a>
```

it is showing URL like this. but I want to show order id instead /value/

```
http://example.com/admin/sales/order/view/order_id/value/key/2949e62fd1786f738a8c1fda0cff5d784aae1fcf29a9fca93ab1abeecf19c69a/
```